# How to place `div` on the same row where `li` is located?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-height: 1em;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: green;
}

.column1 {
  width: 30%;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: green;
}

.column2 {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1"></div>
      <div class="column2"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

In that example my `div` elements are located on the next row:

[image]

But I need they would be located on the same row where `li` number is located. I.e. I need such result:

[image]

How can I get the result which I need?

Comment: `inline-flex` with `width:100%` and `box-sizing:border-box` would work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a "wrapper" so that I can style it with `display:inline-block;`. I think it goes to the next line because `div` is a block element, thus it went to the next line

```css
div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-height: 1em;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: green;
}

.column1 {
  width: 30%;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: green;
}

.column2 {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column1"></div>
          <div class="column2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a list:

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  counter-increment: myIndex;
}

.row:before {
  content: counter(myIndex) ".\00A0";
}

.row div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.column1 {
  width: 30%;
}

.column2 {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1"></div>
  <div class="column2"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column1"></div>
  <div class="column2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your variant is very interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change to `display: inline-flex` on `row`.

It is also recommended to use flex properties on flex items (see comments in CSS)

*To make your CSS slimmer, I also removed a few non-needed properties (the one's they had set is their defaults), such as padding/margin on `div`, flex-direction on `row`, and used the shorthand version for the `border`*

```css
div {
  min-height: 1em;
}
.row {
  display: inline-flex;           /*  changed  */
  width: 100%;                    /*  added    */
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;         /*  added, make border size be within set width  */
}
.column1 {
  flex-basis: 30%;                /*  changed  */
  border-right: 1px solid green;
}
.column2 {
  flex-grow: 1;                   /*  changed, take remaining space  */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1"></div>
      <div class="column2"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

You needed to add width and float properties to your row element.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

This gives exactly the required result. Probably you need to read more about float property in CSS. It will help you a lot in the rest of the project.